# Reading video metadata in javascript

Tags: javascript, video, metadata

I'm working on a website that allows users to upload videos. I would like to order the videos based on the date they were actually recorded, but I can't read the metadata with a server-side tool because the videos are directly uploaded by the client to AWS, without passing through the server.
So I have to read the metadata via javascript during the upload, so I can send them to the server.

I know that I can read files using the FileReader object, but is there any way I can extract the metadata?

Comment: This should do it https://github.com/jDataView/jDataView

Comment: You can get the date last modified easily. Reading actual meta data from the video file is much more difficult. The `loadedmetadata` event is no help. You would need to parse the binary data of the video container format, and the structure will be different between container formats. I imagine some video formats do not contains such information.